# NoSuchMethodError after upgrade WebSphere from 8.5.5.0 to 8.5.5.3

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-portal

I have upgraded my WebSphere 8.5.5.0 to 8.5.5.3. OS is RHEL 6.4

Same application I am able to run on 8.5.5.0 but when I have run it on 8.5.5.3 I got following error in SystemErr.log

```
0000003b SystemErr     R Exception in thread "LT=1:P=137731:O=0:port=41376" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/ibm/CORBA/iiop/OrbTrcLogger.exception(JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

0000003b SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.orbssl.WSSSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.getPeerCertificateChain(WSSSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:580)
0000003b SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSSSLTransportConnection$1.run(WSSSLTransportConnection.java:142)
```

Then I have updated WebSphere Java SDK version to " 7 SR7 (7.0.7.0)" as per  "APAR IX90142" now there is no error into server logs.

But when I try to launch application I am getting following

```
error.java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.OrbTrcLogger.exception(JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at com.ibm.ws.security.orbssl.WSSSLClientSocketFactoryImpl.performSSLHandshakeAndGetSession(WSSSLClientSocketFactoryImpl.java:497)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.orbssl.WSSSLClientSocketFactoryImpl.createSSLSocket(WSSSLClientSocketFactoryImpl.java:210)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSSSLTransportConnection.createSocket(WSSSLTransportConnection.java:236)
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Is your client application running on the same server?

Comment: yes and clients jars are from same server. And same application is running fine without enabling security on same server.

Comment: Try to update to latest Java SDK (7.0.9.0). If it won't fix the issue then create PMR in IBM Support

Comment: Thanks for feedback. with java 7.0.9.0 issue is resolved on 8.5.5.1 version. But still facing same issue with 8.5.5.3.